# || and && (i'm having trouble understanding these logical operator)

Tags: java

[image: The code]

I'm having trouble understanding these "logical operators" 
like, on the line " 19 " why this operator " && " work there but not this operator " || ".

> for my understanding if operand " || " on the right or left side returns "true" so it returns true right ?.
>
> But if the operand " && " on the right or left side returns "false" it
>   returns False right?

So imagine on this line..`(i < name1.length && !rt.equals(name1[i])`is false 
like is not inside of the Arrays it should return false;

but this one 
`( j<name2.length && !rt.equals(name2[j]))`is true ,i though this operator " || " should be fine there not this " && " .

Comment: Copy paste `code` here.

Comment: Show what you tried; [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)'s how to ask a good question

Comment: Whatever you mentioned in the block is correct. If the first condition is already `false`, then using `&&` would cause the second condition to be ignored, and returns `false`. However, you shouldn't replace the `&&` to `||` just because the first condition is `false`, because in reality you wouldn't know what it would evaluate to, otherwise you would be returning a direct `true`/`false`.

Comment: @Mureinik , i see you have edited the question but have pasted the image , please remove it and paste code if you can else dont try to edit.

Comment: @CommonMan I just inlined the OP's image, which isn't great but still better than having a link to it.

Comment: @Mureinik, really man with 190 k rep and still pasting image, i really did not expected this.

Comment: @CommonMan reread my comment.

Comment: @Mureinik, its ok, sorry if i said something wrong, i just tend to learn from old people here.